# My line-element is not staying in its place and keeps on moving with the screen-size

Tags: html, css, line, css-position

I wanted to add some line-arc to my practice page (re-creating a website to practice). I'll add the css here:

```
.line_arc-1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: -75%;
    top: auto;
    right: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 250vw;
    height: 200vw;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

The problem is, when I make a bigger/smaller screen, the lines move with it. It's like they're connected to the bottom of my screen-size.

I've tried to change the position, but then the lines change shape, I'll add a picture of what it's supposed to look like.

[as you can seen the lines are sticky to the bottom, when I go up and down with the inspector, they move as well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvSjL.png) https://www.pagoda.co/ --> real website I'm trying to recreate.

I've tried to change all the items in the CSS (position, bottom). When I remove "bottom" it stick to it's location but it turns upside down. I also tried to add the "transform 90°" then but that doesn’t do anything.

Comment: From the website link it looks as though the arcs are inside a wrapper element which has its own styling, have you also included styling for `.overlay_lines-wrapper` ?

Comment: You could try with `top: -100vw` so it's relative to the top of the page. You should probably change the left to vw too so it's the same units. And yeah, they are gonna move cause you are using a relative screen size with "vw" instead of static pixel size.

Comment: Thanks both for your suggestions, I tried both of them, the lines still move